# How to make background color of image transparent?

Tags: css

I have an arrow image, I would like to make its background color to be equal to default background which is lightblue. Also at the border of the image there are some white spaces which I am trying to remove. I used opacity property but that is not helping in achieving this styling.

Here is my css code

```
.rm-section .rm-links .m .rm p:after {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 150px;
  content: url(/etc/designs/fai/clientlibs/base/images/down_arrow_icon.jpg);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
padding: 24px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: if your image is like this as natural, you can't modify it via CSS, you need to edit with some image editor before add it to HTML/CSS. (Also a .jpg doesn't have transparency)

Comment: Instead of using a jpg, which had no transparency, why not use a png or gif which do?

Comment: Yes image is like this from beginning

Comment: So, there's no way to edit it by CSS. You need a .png image with a transparent background.

Comment: I used opacity and seems that its working..but probably I have different html that you do? Have a look in the fiddle below 

https://jsfiddle.net/bvd4m8qj/2/
and let us know :)

Comment: Opacity is fading the image too

Comment: Then yeah... you need to edit it with an image editor :)

Comment: Also, you can use free online libraries that have fonts with images like this ([Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons) is a good example).

Comment: Is it possible with svg format?

Answer (score 3):

**Follow these steps it's very simple**

1. Burn the background image online at the following website
   [link](https://burner.bonanza.com/background_burns/selected)
2. Download it from png
3. Do not set the background of the image in css

Example Image See the Next and Back buttons [link](http://wassim-al-ahmad.22web.org)

Comment: Hey, You may have accidentally removed the first burner link

Comment: Yes the link is diferent

Comment: sorry I will fix it